# What does @CLS in Windows Batch File Do

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to suppress a warning which says the following, but doesn't seem to effect the outcome of the file.

```
'\\Server\Share\Dir\'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

I found a solution here >> https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24439606/How-to-remove-UNC-paths-are-not-supported-Defaulting-to-windows-directory.html

which was to add `@CLS` to the beginning of the batch file, but I have no idea what it does. Can anybody explain?

Comment: You can get help with any command on Windows by typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark.

Comment: Run in a cmd window `cls /?` and you know what the CLear Screen command does. `@` at beginning avoids printing the command itself into console window if echo mode is on as by default. The usage of `@cls` at top of the batch file is no real solution. It just makes the information (not error) message not visible for user of a batch file.

Comment: Your batch file stored on a network resource and started directly from the network resource using a UNC path is hopefully coded to work independent on what is the current directory because Windows changes the current directory from UNC accessed folder to %SystemRoot% (Windows folder). This is done by Windows by default because many console applications do not support a UNC path as working (current) directory and fail in this case.

Comment: @Squashman yet it seems almost 2K people have chosen to use google to find the answer and have ended up on this post. I bet this post gets over 10K views in a few years or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is faster then I can see it, Windows is displaying the error message, then clearing the screen when it reaches the first line of my script.

```
C:\>CLS /?
Clears the screen.

CLS
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to redirect the output of the command that is causing this message? This is accomplished by appending the operators `1>nul` and/or `2>nul` to the end of the line.
Example: `dir AB:\ 1>nul 2>nul` Will suppress any output, even the error message that the drive "AB:" does not exist.

The 1 stands for "normal output" (equivalent to just `>nul`) while the 2 stands for the error output stream.
My guess is, you need the latter.

Also, if you want to use a UNC-Path you need to have a look at the command `pushd`. See this [example on StackOverflow](https://superuser.com/questions/282963/browse-an-unc-path-using-windows-cmd-without-mapping-it-to-a-network-drive)